# SQL Query selecting from two separate tables using a order clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
tickets
ticket_updates
```

and i am trying to run a query where it shows data from the tickets table and `order by` the latest `datetime` in the `ticket_updates` table

```
SELECT * from tickets where status = 'Completed' order by ??? DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

`ticketnumber` in the `tickets` table matches `ticketnumber` in the `ticket_updates` table

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tickets AS t
JOIN ticket_updates AS tu ON t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber
WHERE status = 'Completed'
ORDER BY tu.datetime DESC LIMIT 50
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to summarize the `ticket_updates` table to get what you want:

```
select t.*
from tickets t join
     (select ticketid, max(datetime) as max_datetime
      from ticket_updates
      group by ticketid
     ) tu
     on t.ticketid = tu.max_datetime
order by tu.max_datetime desc
limit 0, 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables, then order by:

```
SELECT a.*
from tickets a, ticket_updates b
where a.ticketnumber = b.ticketnumber and
a.status = 'Completed'
order by b.YOUR_DATETIME_FIELD DESC LIMIT 0,50
```